# Java, шахматная доска

Tags: javascript, java, алгоритм

У нас есть квадратная доска размером n * n, ячейки которой могут принимать значения булевого типа: #t - окрашенная ячейка, #f - пустая(не окрашенная). Доска считается заполненной правильно только в том случае, если у окрашенной ячейки нету соседей справа, слева, сверху и снизу(только по диагонали) Вот так:

```
X 0 X
0 X 0
X 0 O
```

Нужно написать метод method(boolean[] field, int n), который будет принимать одномерный(!) массив, размер доски n и выдавать правильность заполнения доски(#t, #f).

Верно:

```
X 0 0 0
0 X 0 X
0 0 0 0
X 0 0 0
```

Не верно:

```
X 0 0 0
X 0 0 X
0 0 X 0
X 0 0 0
```

Нумерация элементов в массиве соответственно:

```
0   1   2   3
4   5   6   7
8   9  10  11
12 13  14  15
```

В заключении нужно создать метод, который будет подсчитывать количество возможных правильно заполненных полей для определенного n. Т.е создавая наивным способом все возможные варианты заполнения полей и проверяя их с помощью method.

**Огромное спасибо за любые подсказки!** 
В интернете искал, нашел решение задачи про ладью, которая мне показалась не применимой в данной проблеме.

Мои собственные наброски(не работает для четных n):

```
public static boolean gueltig1(boolean[] feld, int n){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++){
                if(i + n <= n * n - 1){
                    if (feld[i] == true &&
                        (feld[Math.abs(i + 1)] == true ||
                        feld[Math.abs(i - 1)] == true ||
                        feld[Math.abs(i + n)] == true ||
                        feld[Math.abs(i - n)] == true)){
                        return false;}
                }
                if(i + n > n * n - 1 && i + 1 < n * n - 1){
                    if (feld[i] == true &&
                        (feld[Math.abs(i + 1)] == true ||
                        feld[Math.abs(i - 1)] == true ||
                        feld[Math.abs(i - n)] == true)){
                        return false;}

                }
                if(i == n * n - 1){
                        if (feld[i] == true &&
                            (feld[Math.abs(i - 1)] == true ||
                            feld[Math.abs(i - n)] == true)){
                            return false;}

                }
            }
            return true;
    }
```

Или так:

```
public static boolean gueltig(boolean[] feld, int n){
        for (int i = n + 1; i < n * n; i++){

            if(feld[i] == true &&
                    (feld[i - n] == true ||
                    feld[Math.abs(i - 1)] == true)){
                    return false;}
            }
            return true;
    }
```

P.S.: Начинающий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение на Java.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] board = {
            true, false, true, false, false, true,
            false, true, false, false, true, false,
            false, false, true, false, false, true,
            true, false, false, false, true, false,
            false, false, false, false, false, false,
            true, false, false, true, false, true,
    };

    System.out.println(isCorrect(board));
}

private static boolean isCorrect(boolean[] board) {
    Neighbors neighbor = new Neighbors(board);
    return neighbor.isCorrect();
}

static class Neighbors {
    boolean left;
    boolean right;
    boolean top;
    boolean bottom;

    boolean[] board;
    int dim;

    Neighbors(boolean[] board) {
        this.board = board;
        initDim();
    }

    private void initDim() {
        double boardDimension = Math.sqrt(board.length);
        if (boardDimension % 1 != 0) {
            System.err.println("Warning: you must pass array that have n * n elements. In this case the correct result is not guaranteed.");
        }
        dim = (int) boardDimension;
    }

    boolean isColored(int position, char operation, int offset) {
        try {
            // Если на "краю" и если проверяем вправо или влево.
            if (isOnEdge(position) && offset != dim) {
                return false;
            }
            if (operation == '+') {
                return board[position + offset];
            } else {
                return board[position - offset];
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {

        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isOnEdge(int position) {
        return (position + 1) % dim == 0 || (position) % dim == 0;
    }

    private boolean hasColoredNeighbor() {
        return left || right || top || bottom; // Хотя бы один сосед сосед окрашен.
    }

    boolean isCorrect() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            boolean field = board[i];
            if (field) {
                left = isColored(i, '-', 1);
                right = isColored(i, '+', 1);
                top = isColored(i, '-', dim);
                bottom = isColored(i, '+', dim);
            }
            if (hasColoredNeighbor()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Большущее спасибо!!! Это именно то что я искал! Браво!

Answer (score 2):

Реализовал на js...
Функция neighbors возвращает всех соседей ячейки доски.
checkField сам метод.

```js
var n = 4
var array = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
console.log(checkField(array, n));

function neighbors(pos, array, n) {
  tmp = [];
  if (typeof array[pos - 1] != 'undefined') {
    tmp.push(array[pos - 1])
  }
  if (typeof array[pos + 1] != 'undefined') {
    tmp.push(array[pos + 1])
  }
  if (typeof array[pos - n] != 'undefined') {
    tmp.push(array[pos - n])
  }
  if (typeof array[pos + n] != 'undefined') {
    tmp.push(array[pos + n])
  }
  return tmp;
}

function checkField(array, n) {
  var check = true;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length && array[i] && check; i++) {
    var _neighbors = neighbors(i, array, n);
    for (j = 0; j < _neighbors.length; j++) {
      if (array[i] == _neighbors[j]) {
        check = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return check;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! 
На данный момент не особо ясно как реализовать метод neighbors в java, но тут гугл в помощь

Comment: ну это самая обычная функция, где то там в основах должна быть...

Answer (score 1):

минифицированная версия на js, преимущество: не делает лишних шагов, проверка останавливается на первой неправильной ячейке. аргументы функции (проверяемый массив, длина строки), результат true/false.

```js
var array = [
        1, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0
    ],
    board = [
        true, false, true, false, false, true,
        false, true, false, false, true, false,
        false, false, true, false, false, true,
        true, false, false, false, true, false,
        false, false, false, false, false, false,
        true, false, false, true, false, true
    ],
    test = [
        1, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0
    ];

function chec(d, c) {
    return !d.some(function(a, b) {
        if (!a) return a;
        a = [b + c, b - c];
        b % c && a.push(b - 1);
        (b + 1) % c && a.push(b + 1);
        return a.filter(function(a) {
            return 0 <= a && a < d.length && d[a]
        }).length
    })
};
console.log(chec(array, 4));//true
console.log(chec(board, 6));//true
console.log(chec(test, 4));//false
```